# Can't find my invalid character (ORA-00911)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating an application that runs SQL queries for us. I've copied this query from a script that is working, but when I paste it in SQL developer or vs code it gives me a ORA-00911 error. I already tried to remove the ; from the query, but it didn't help. Am I maybe pasting it wrong?

```
    SELECT To_char(requestmessagetimestamp, 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss DY') AS "DATE",
       serviceid,
       requesttype,
       requestspecification,
       bfa.faultdescription,
       CASE
         WHEN requestmessage IS NOT NULL THEN dbms_lob.Substr(
                                              Substr(bMes.requestmessage,
       Instr(bMes.requestmessage, 'SourceSystem'
       , 1)
                                   + Length('SourceSystem') + 1,
       (
       Instr(bMes.requestmessage, 'SourceSystem', 1,
       2) -
       Instr(bMes.requestmessage, 'SourceSystem'
       , 1) - Length('SourceSystem') - 3 )))
       END                                                        AS
       sourceSystem,
       CASE
         WHEN requestmessage IS NOT NULL THEN dbms_lob.Substr(
                                              Substr(bMes.requestmessage,
         Instr(bMes.requestmessage, 'EventId'
       ,
       1)
       + Length('EventId') + 1, (
       Instr(bMes.requestmessage, 'EventId', 1, 2) -
       Instr(bMes.requestmessage, 'EventId'
       , 1) - Length('EventId') - 3 )))
       END                                                        AS EventId,
       bint.messageid,
       bint.relatesto,
       systimestamp
FROM   baseintegrationheaders bint
       LEFT JOIN basemessages bMes
              ON bMes.relatesto = bint.relatesto
       LEFT JOIN basefaults bfa
              ON bfa.relatesto = bint.relatesto
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND requestmessagetimestamp BETWEEN ( Trunc(systimestamp, 'hh') +
                                             Floor(
           To_char(systimestamp, 'mi') / %% period %% )
                                                 *
                                                   %% period %%
                                                     / 1440 )
                                               - %% period %% / 1440 AND
                                           Trunc(
                                               systimestamp, 'hh') +
           Floor(
           To_char(systimestamp, 'mi') / %% period
           %% ) *
                                           %% period %%
           / 1440
       AND bint.technicaldomain = 'WB'
       AND bint.serviceid IN ( 'AST_GPSBatch_Reply-bridge',
                               'AST_GPSOnline_Reply-bridge',
                                                     'AST_GPS_Request-bridge' )
       AND requesttype NOT IN ( 'appRunning', 'appEnd', 'BridgeStart',
                                'appEnd',
                                'appMQEnd', )
       AND ( ( requesttype = 'BridgeRequest'
               AND faultindication = 'true' )
              OR ( requesttype <> 'BridgeRequest' ) )
ORDER  BY bint.messageid,
          1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run it, client should point to position which raised the error. Here you go:

```
<snip>
 67                OR ( requesttype <> 'BridgeRequest' ) )
 68  ORDER  BY bint.messageid,
 69            1;
           To_char(systimestamp, 'mi') / %% period %% )
                                         *
ERROR at line 41:
ORA-00911: invalid character


SQL>
```

Bunch of `%%` characters is *invalid*.

---

When removed and reexecuted:

```
 68  ORDER  BY bint.messageid,
 69            1;
       LEFT JOIN basefaults bfa
                 *
ERROR at line 36:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
```

Right; that's expected, I don't have your tables and can't run that script.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right. It gave me a new error that "PERIOD" is invalid. Will create a new question for that. Thanks again

Comment: It is ALWAYS (in this code) related to %%, e.g. `%% period %%` so - what does it represent, actually? Is it a parameter, or what?